# android webview share url only work on notitlebar theme

Tags: android, webview

I create an android app using webview. It works. Then I add a share intent to share current url of webview. This only works when share icon is not in title bar, the icon comes by clicking on android menu button. But when share icon comes in title bar it does not work.

My webactivity code is

```
package com.android.androidwebviewexample;

import com.android.androidwebviewexample.R;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;

public class WebActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webcontent);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl(myurlname);


    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            String url2=myurlname;

            if (url != null && url.startsWith(url2)){
                return false;
                } 
            else  {
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
                }
        }
    });


}
private ShareActionProvider myShareActionProvider;
@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
         MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
         myShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)item.getActionProvider();
         myShareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);

         myShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
         return true;
     }


     private Intent createShareIntent() {
      Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, webView.getUrl());
            return shareIntent;
        }

     @Override
     public final boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         switch (item.getItemId()) {
             case R.id.menu_item_share:
                 shareURL();
         }
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }

         private void shareURL() {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, webView.getUrl());
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share This!"));
        }

}
```

part of android manifest that works is

```
<activity
        android:name=".WebActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
```

part of android manifest that does not works is

```
<activity
        android:name=".WebActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

How to solve it.

Comment: Can you post your logcat trace?

Comment: I/dalvikvm-heap(1947): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.414MB for 635808-byte allocation
I/Choreographer(1947): Skipped 83 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
E/chromium_net(1947): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/backend_impl.cc:1107: [0521/012816:ERROR:backend_impl.cc(1107)] Critical error found -8
W/chromium_net(1947): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/storage_block-inl.h:119: [0521/012816:WARNING:storage_block-inl.h(119)] Failed data load.
D/chromium(1947): Unknown chromium error: -401
D/TilesManager(1947): Starting TG #0, 0xb9078fb0